# Запрет на многократное выполнение действия

Tags: jquery

Вот, допустим, у меня есть такой код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.close_userbar').click(function () {
        $('.for_not_logged').hide('drop', 1700);
        $('.open_userbar').delay(1700).show('drop', 1700);
        $('.open_userbar').click(function () {
            $('.open_userbar').hide('drop', 700);
            $('.for_not_logged').delay(700).show('drop', 1000);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Мне надо сделать так, чтобы функция не выполнялась несколько раз при многократном нажатии (потому что ведь есть такие, кто будут троллить); извиняюсь за не правильный лексикон... Я просто не знаю такой функции, подскажите. Ах да, и еще когда все функции успешно выполнились, нужно чтобы все так же работало, как и при первом запуске... главное, запретить многократное нажатие, а разрешить только на одно, вот в принципе как-то так. )))

**Добавлено.**

В общей сумме, как должно выглядеть; хочу запрет на

```
$('.open_userbar').click(function(){
$('.open_userbar').hide('drop', 700);
$('.for_not_logged').delay(700).show('drop', 1000);
```

или так что ли

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.close_userbar').click(function () {
        $('.for_not_logged').hide('drop', 1700);
        $('.open_userbar').delay(1700).show('drop', 1700);
        $('.open_userbar').click(function (kap) {
            $('.open_userbar').hide('drop', 700);
            $('.for_not_logged').delay(700).show('drop', 1000);
        });
    });
});
sync = {
    active: false,
    action: function (kap) {
        $('.open_userbar').hide('drop', 700);
    },
    push: function () {
        this.active = false;
    },
    pop: function () {
        if (this.active == false) {
            this.active = true;
            this.action();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот это вам должно подойти.

```
sync = {
  active: false,
  action: function (){
    //ваша функция
  },
  push: function (){
    this.active = false;
  },
  pop: function (){
    if ( this.active == false ){
      this.active = true;
      this.action();
    }
  }
}
```

По завершении ваших действий, нужно вызвать sync.push();

Для вашего случая, как вариант

```
sync = {
   id: 0,
   active: false,
   action: function(){
      clearTimeout( this.id );
      sync.push();
   },
   delay: function(delay){
      this.id = setTimeout( this.action, delay );
   },
   push: function (){
      clearTimeout( this.id );
      this.active = false;
   },
   pop: function (){
      if ( this.active == false ){
         this.active = true;
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.close_userbar').click(function(){
      if ( sync.pop() ){
         $('.for_not_logged').hide('drop', 1700);
         $('.open_userbar').delay(1700).show('drop', 1700);
         sync.delay(3400);
      }
   });

   $('.open_userbar').click(function(){
      if ( sync.pop() ){
         $('.open_userbar').hide('drop', 700);
         $('.for_not_logged').delay(700).show('drop', 1000);
         sync.delay(1700);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Хорошее решение.

Comment: псс и как я должен это встроить?

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Comment: После этого кода у меня ничего не работает.